# Python arguments passed with quotes

Tags: python, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to pass file list to my python script via argument:

```
python script.py -o aaa -s bbb "filename.txt" "filename2.txt" "file name3.txt"
```

Unfortunately ArgumentParser is ignoring quotes and instead of giving list of 3 files it gives me list of 4 elements as followed:

```
1) "filename.txt"
2) "filename2.txt"
3) "file
4) name3.txt"
```

It completely ignores quotes. How to make it work with quotes?

Comment: What were you expecting ?

Comment: AFAIK this all depends on the shell. In bash the quotes would be removed before passing the arguments to the program. No idea how windows(or other shells) handles quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Hard without seeing what you're using or any code.
Your shell *may* be interfering, you may need to escape the spaces with `\`.

Example:
`python script.py -o a -f "file1.txt" "file\ 2.csv"`

Comment: I doubt that it is the shell's fault.

Answer (score 0):

Is hard without code but considering you are using `sys.argv[]` you can easily pass the file arguments with quotes like when you need a file or argv with blank spaces: `python script.py "myFile.txt" "otherFile.jpeg"`
Try this simple code to understand:

```
import sys

for n, p in enumerate(sys.argv):
    print("Parameter: %d = %s") % (n, p))`
```

You can see that first argv is the file name you are running.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that this is not python's fault. I'm calling python script from inside of bash script and this make mess with quotes as parameters.